# Error Channels: how to configure for config based destination

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

I have a 2 spring cloud stream consumers each consuming 2 different messages:

```
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
      function:
        definition: OneConsumer; TwoConsumer;
      bindings:
        oneConsumer-in-0:
          destination: destination-1-qa
          group: processor-qa
          binder: binder-one
        twoConsumer-in-0:
          destination: destination-2-qa
          group: processor-qa
          binder: binder-one
```

If any failure happens, it get's thrown into an error channel to handle the failure.

As seen above, my destination and and group both are for my qa environment, but when I go to prod, all my destination and groups will change to the prod setting. How can I configure the ServiceActivator to be config based instead of hard coding the destination like below:

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "destination-1-qa.processor-qa.errors")
  public void processErrorMessage(ErrorMessage errorMessage) {}

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "destination-2-qa.processor-qa.errors")
  public void processErrorMessage(ErrorMessage errorMessage) {}
```

If my destination or my group changes, I would also need to do a code change to change the inputChannel.

I'm looking for something like this or something that can consumer based on the binding, not the destination or can be config based.

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "oneConsumer-in-0.errors")
  public void processErrorMessage(ErrorMessage errorMessage) {}
```